# Почему я не могу использовать onclick в методе angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

```
<li ng-click="archive($index)"><a> test </a>
<script>
app.controller('ClickController', ['$scope', function($scope, $el) { 


$scope.archive = function($index){

 // мне нужна имитация клика на другой элемент
 // но возникает ошибка
 //  $(".switch .lever").click()

 // вот это событие срабатывает, но выдает ошибку в консоль
 document.querySelector(".switch .lever").click();

  /* angular.element('.switch .lever').triggerHandler('click');  не срабатывает*/

  }

}]);
</script>
```

Если вынести $(".switch .lever").click() за пределы функции, все работает, что делать, мне нужно, чтобы отработала внутри этой функции?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главная ошибка тут - использование доступа к `DOM` напрямую и вызов обработчика `click`.

Так как при взаимодействии с пользователем: вводе текста, кликов и т.д. ангуляр запускает digest-цикл, вызов напрямую обработчика `click` - запустит его еще раз, собственно на это и ругается ангуляр.

Так как ко второму элементу наверняка привязан тот же `ng-click` - нужно вызывать непосредственно привязанное выражение.

<sub>для разработки лучше использовать не минифицированные версии библиотеки. Они дают более информативный текст ошибки.</sub>

Comment: подскажите, как переписать код? я так понял, нужно привязать другой обработчик и вызвать его?

Comment: @splincode, покажи [mcve], который есть сейчас. В ответе я уже сказал, что нужно просто вызвать напрямую выражение, которое указано для ng-click второго элемента